# How to add custom CSS in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm new to coding, very new and have some code that I believe needs to be added to `"custom CSS"` in my e-commerce site. This is to remove the issue of bullet points appearing on the top left of products `(screenshot attached)`, when using the product category field with `woocommerce`.

I've done this through my theme but it doesn't work. Any ideas?
thank you! Such a huge learning curve and I appreciate the help.

[Snapshot of dots on product pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Bbf.jpg)

Comment: add css : list-style : none; on particular class

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Where do I add/edit this? as I said, I'm really new to coding so excuse the ignorance on my part.

Comment: can you give me url of your website. so i can add perfect class for this.

Comment: http://new.launcestonflowers.com.au/new/

Comment: it only occurs on the pages that use visual composer, woocommerce field editor for "product categories".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add in /new/bouquets/inspector-stylesheet.css

```
.woocommerce ul li { list-style:none !important;}
```

or

```
.woocommerce .item { list-style:none !important;}
```

Comment: thanks so much, however I'm looking through in Cpanel file directory and cannot locate the css page you reference.

Comment: I think this file is inside subdomain

Comment: You can add this code any one of css file which is included on page

Comment: No luck. After an "all file" search it's not finding it in any directory.

Comment: You can also add this file. find this path : wp-content/themes/sw-paradise/css/app-green.css

Comment: You are awesome! It worked brilliantly. No dots any more. Thank you so much for your time and patience and help.